# Schedule reboot from WiX deferred custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I've got a WiX deferred custom action that conditionally modifies some registry keys. For the changes to take effect, a reboot is required. I'd like the user to get the standard dialog box that prompts them to reboot after the installation completes.

How can I schedule a reboot from a deferred custom action?

Comment: [Some pointers on conditioning ScheduleReboot so it doesn't trigger an undesired reboot prompt in the wrong installation modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840273/reboot-on-install-dont-reboot-on-uninstall).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you have a custom action doing something that MSI/WiX knows how to do natively?

A cleaner approach would be to have registry values associated with a component that has the needed condition.  Then you can have a simple custom action trigged by that same condition call MsiSetMode with the MSIRUNMODE_REBOOTATEND argument. If you are using C#/DTF that's session.SetMode(InstallRunMode.RebootAtEnd).

This way if the install is aborted, canceled, failed it can roll back the registry changes.

Comment: I do so much other *stuff* in the custom action I never even thought about just using WiX to do this! Inspired by your answer, I now simply have a conditional `ScheduleReboot` element in `InstallExecuteSequence`

Comment: Bravo on the ScheduleReboot action.  That's even better.  Always try to eliminate custom actions wherever possible. It results in a much better installer.